# React Native: How do I create an event listener to trigger an event when screen is unlocked and when screen is locked?

Tags: events, screen, react-native, react-native-ios

How do I create an event listener to trigger an event when the screen is unlocked and when the screen is locked using React Native for both iOS and Android?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't. You could write a native module which gives you state of your phone or you can use [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) to see in which state your app is.